# Models in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Why are models not in a separate `Model` folder in the api template? The original template comes with `WeatherForecast.cs` as a separate file just by itself.

Are we not supposed to have a folder for models?

Comment: Agreed, It is a boiler plate code provided by the template within Visual Studio

Comment: if i add one manually how do i reference it in my controller?

Comment: Need to add the namespace ( within which you create model) within controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this template you actually get minimal settings for ASP.NET project as `program.cs` and `startup.cs` with minimum configuration.

Then you choose how your folders will be located, depending on what you are going to do. If you want to make a couple of controllers with couple of methods, and you are not going to expand the functionality, you can write all the functionality of your program there and create two folders: controllers and models. In the case where you need to build a large application with a lot of logic, you need to use common web application architectures.

You can read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture) and find a right direction for searching, but it is more than just "separate file and folders", this is a very big topic for thought.